# YouTube API Java demo: youtube-api-samples do not compile

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

I've downloaded and tried to compile some YouTube API demo applications from the youtube-api-samples that is officially recommended by Google.

https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/downloads/list

I was suprised that none of the examples in this zip actually compiles via maven.

```
Missing artifact com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:jar:v3-rev8-1.12.0-beta
```

Tried to take the latest version of this jar from this page:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-youtube</artifactId>
      <version>v3-rev70-1.16.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
```

This introduced multiple compilation errors due to jars incompatibility.
So, my question to you and to Google folks, what's wrong with your demos? Could you supply internet community with at least one working example?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check out the project via git clone.

In the meantime we'll update the download package.